# Activar modo Live Api Paypal

Tags: php, api, paypal

Estoy habilitando la opción de pagos en mi web a través de la Api de Paypal, he realizado las pruebas con el modo sandbox y todo funciona correctamente; el problema está en que quiero ahora probarla en modo live para que quede listo para producción y no puedo habilitar la opción de Live, quiero saber si hay algún tipo de requisito para habilitar en esa función. Adjunto imágenes:

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

[image: Imagen 3]

Answer (score 0):

Se Debe agregar el siguiente código debajo de la declaración de las credenciales:

```
$paypal->setConfig([
'mode'=>'live',
'http.ConnectionTimeOut'=>30,
'log.LogEnabled' => false,
'log.FileName'=>'',
'log.LogLevel' =>'FINE',
'validation.level'=>'log' ]);
```

Con eso le especificamos que se active el modo live. :)

Comment: Despues de activar el codigo, ya funciona todo?? o toca activar algun token de Paypal por que yo tambien tengo el mismo problema no me realiza la compra, entra en modo paypal live pero no me llega el dinero a mi cuenta

Comment: Ya funcionó todo, correctamente.